# how to scroll over image in recycler view

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programming and I am trying to scroll my recycler view over image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/rootRL"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="160dp"
 android:background="@drawable/mydrawable">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
    android:id="@+id/rv"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

When I scroll ,the recycler view scrolls under the image not over it.How can i achieve this effect ?

Comment: Remove "android:layout_marginTop="160dp"" from recyclerview and try again.

Comment: @Sabari I want to start scrolling from that point

Comment: You are setting image as background image for framelayout, you want to scroll the recyckerview over that, am I correct?

Comment: yes thats exactly what I want to do..

Comment: Here you are setting framelayout height as 160dp and also setting margintop as 160dp for recyckerview. I think you can set margintop for framelayout as160dp, not to recyckerview.

Comment: I will post a sample code for that...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

**Using FrameLayout by setting backgroundImage:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rootRL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tips"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

**Using LinearLayout by setting backgroundImage:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rootRL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tips"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Using RelativeLayout by setting backgroundImage:**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rootRL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tips">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Using RelativeLayout with ImageView:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rootRL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/tips" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have posted the sample code(4 methods) to achieve your goal. I hope it will helpful to you.